# Whoosh search results not Json serializable

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, whoosh

How do I make the results from Whoosh search results JSON serializable so I can return that data back to the client?

Whoosh search output (list of python objects):

```
[<Hit {'content': 'This is the second example.', 'path': '/b', 'icon': '/icons/sheep.png', 'title': 'Second try'}>, <Hit {'content': 'Examples are many second.', 'path': '/c', 'icon': '/icons/book.png', 'title': "Third time's the charm"}>]
```

Error when doing this:

```
return JsonReponse({"data": whoosh_results})



TypeError: <Hit {'content': 'This is the second example.', 'path': '/b', 'icon': '/icons/sheep.png', 'title': 'Second try'}> is not JSON serializable
```

I have tried making a separate class

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    icon=serializers.CharField()
    content=serializers.CharField()
    path=serializers.CharField()
    title=serializers.CharField()
```

but the error becomes that the Hit object has no attribute 'icon'

Comment: can you show the code used to search?

Comment: Tried wrapping it in `dict`? Like `return JsonReponse({"data": dict(whoosh_results)})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Igonato points out, if you wrap your `whoos_results` in a `dict` you can make them `JSON serializable`:

```
response = dict(whoosh_results)
return JsonReponse({"data": response)
```

You can even take individual parts of your dictionary out:

```
return JsonReponse({"content": response['content'], 'path': response['path']})
```

Good luck :)

Comment: Had to loop through the array and then dict each python object to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: No prob mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Feels a bit ugly, but this works. Maybe somebody has a better solution

```
return JsonReponse({"data": [dict(hit) for hit in whoosh_results]})
```